# Specify input files in bash script

Tags: bash, user-input, bioinformatics, fastq

My issue is with a bash script I am writing. I need to specify input files for a tool called STAR, which is an aligner for bioinformatic use. It has a flag --readFilesIn. In my case this takes two sets of multiple files (fastq files) comma separated, the two sets separated by space; the input looks like:

```
STAR [OPTIONS] --readFilesIn fq_r1_1,fq_r1_2,fq_r1_3 fq_r2_1,fq_r2_2,fq_r2_3
```

Because each set of fastq files differs in number and name I had thought of using below, where $files is the dir containing the fastq files.

```
dir $files | cut -d " " -f 9 | sed 's/\s *//g' | grep _r1_ | paste -sd ","
```

This produces the correct format, but the aligner doesn't accept the input. I have tried writing to file and giving it this but that doesn't work either. What is the convention for bash in this instance?

Many thanks in advance,

Bruce.

How can I make the aligner accept this. It wants it as in my first example.

Comment: Have you tried: `STAR [OPTIONS] --readFilesIn fq_r1* fq_r2*`

Comment: Did try the wildcards, it gives a segmentation fault, presumably the format of input is wrong. Below works, thanks for your help anyway, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will the following work?

```
group1=( fq_r1_* )
group2=( fq_r2_* )
( IFS=,; STAR [OPTIONS] --readFilesIn "${group1[*]}" "${group2[*]}" )
```

(Running the command inside a subshell to avoid the need to preserve the current value, if any, of `IFS`).